# Higher Order Component - React Native - Invariant Violation Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use `HOC` in `ReactNative` project. But getting `Invariant Violation Error`. Below is the code sample:

**IconComponent.js:** Returns the default component.

```
export class IconComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Image
                source={...}
                style={...} />
        );
    }
}
```

**HomeScreen.js:** Renders the main screen. Here getting **Invariant Violation Error**.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {
                this.getCustomizedIconComponent()
            }
            <SomeView />
        </View>
    );
}

getCustomizedIconComponent = () => {
    const CustomizedIconHOC = getCustomizedIcon(IconComponent, "Custom Text");
    return CustomizedIconHOC;
}
```

**CustomizedIconHOC.js:** Returns custom component.

```
export const getCustomizedIcon = (Comp, customString) => {
    class HOC extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <AnotherCustomView label={customString}/>
                    <Comp />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    return HOC;
};
```

**Error Message:**

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Any pointers on what was the issue and how to fix?!

Comment: <SomeView> isnt closed?

Comment: That's a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: can you put the entire error message?

Comment: Your `HomeScreen.js`'s `render` should have a return statement enclosing your UI.

Comment: We would appreciate if you can put all relevant code in the question. This isn't helping us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Its a common error. Just check the lat change you made before the error. Probably some view isn't closed or accidental strings inside the return

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the instance of the component

```js
getCustomizedIconComponent = () => {
    const CustomizedIconHOC = getCustomizedIcon(IconComponent, "Custom Text");
    return <CustomizedIconHOC />;
}
```

Or

```js
render() {
    const CustomizedIcon = this.getCustomizedIconComponent()

    return (
        <View>
            <CustomizedIcon />
            <SomeView />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Note that doing it this way it will create a new component on every re-render